# source code about commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu

where can I found source files (in C language) about unix Commands (ls, sleep, cd etc).

I've downloaded the kernel linux-2.6.39-rc3, but there are no source about linux command.

thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Why  would the kernel source would include the source for user commands?  The kernel is that which runs in kernel mode. Commands of course run in user mode.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about GNU/Linux or actual UNIX-based systems, such as Solaris? Because they are not equal each other.

Comment: I'm talking about Ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the generic Linux commands come from `coreutils` http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ there might be some missing there, but everything you asked specifically about should be found in coreutils source.

the kernel source doesn't contain any userland programs in it.

Comment: You can browse the git repo for coreutils online as well: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=summary

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Coreutils is already installed, but I don't know how it works. I try to find a good tutorial to understand Coreutils, it seems to be quite difficult.

Comment: In fact, I've found many source files in the src directory. thanks !

Comment: A lot of the coreutils source just involves thin wrappers around kernel syscalls. If you want to really understand what's going on with commands like `ls` and `cd` two good places to start are the `coreutils` source and the `man` page for syscalls (`man syscalls`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using debian based os then u can use

```
dpkg -S command
```

to find the package it is present in and then

```
apt-get source package
```

to download the source. You can find similar commands on other machines.

Comment: `dpkg -S ls` returns 5731 packages on my system. You're not seriously expecting someone to go through all of them, are you? Also, it's "you".

Answer (score 1):

Pickup the GNU coreutils @ http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/coreutils/ and this includes a lot of these commands.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sudo apt-get build-dep core-utils
apt-get source core-utils --compile
```

to get **and compile** everything in core-utils from scratch